# phpmyadmin error message autoload.php missing or unreadable

Tags: apache2, php, phpmyadmin

Trying to update phpmyadmin to version 4.7.  Failed at that, now when I go to localhost/phpmyadmin I get this error message:

```
File ./vendor/autoload.php missing or not readable.
```

Most likely you did not run Composer to install library files.

Is there a way to fix this?
Any and all advice appreciated.

Comment: I gave up and expanded the .zip file for phpMyAdmin 4.7.8 into a temp directory, then copied all the subdirectories and files into /usr/share/phpmyadmin from the command line.  Restarted Apache2 and everything worked.  I was not aware that Archive Manager would expand everything, zip file included, into the target directory.  That was the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your directory which your nginx/apache is taking your phps.

```
sudo composer install
```

ok.
If it says that composer didnt installed then go [this link](https://getcomposer.org/download/) and follow instructions then do it again

```
sudo composer install
```